# Automatically use SQL Server Database to automatically URL rewrite querystring parameters to subdomains

Tags: windows, url, iis, url-rewriting

Say we have website [www.Portal.com](http://www.Portal.com) which  contains details about multiple businesses.   eg. businessA which has an of (say) ID=123 should show on a page such as [www.portal.com/show.aspx?BusinessID=123](http://www.portal.com/show.aspx?BusinessID=123)

However, I'd like it to appear  as a subdomain rather than a querystring parameter so as to make it easier to remember for humans.  eg.    businessA.portal.com    ( instead of [www.portal.com/show.aspx?BusinessID=123](http://www.portal.com/show.aspx?BusinessID=123) )

Notice that the subdomain name is NOT part of one of the querystring parameters.  (..though i could add one more querystring parameter if that would help).  But I remember a long time ago reading somewhere that there is an easy 1-line way to link IIS url rewriting to a SQL Server table.

What is the easiest way to achieve this in IIS on Windows Server 2019, in an automated way for all businesses in the SQL Server database?  I'm not good with url-rewriting rules.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not good with url-rewriting rules.

Comment: You will have to be good at something, such as wring your own custom provider, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

Comment: If you just want to rewrite or redirect `www.portal.com/show.aspx?BusinessID=123` to `businessA.portal.com`, then you only need to use url rewrite, but if you want to link IIS url rewriting to a SQL Server table, this requirement is very vague, you need to share your attempts.